# How to redirect url into error page thorugh rewrite rule

Tags: webserver, websphere

> This is my url
>
> https://www.test.com/acheck/wcheck/logout
>
> if i inject something between url like this
>   https://www.test.com/acheck5.1/test1/wcheck/logout it is routing to
>   valid page instead of error page.
>
> in httpd.conf file i write rule like this but it's not working. can
>   some guide on this
>
> RewriteRule  /acheck*/([A-Za-z0-9-])/logout
>   https://www-test.com/acheck
>
> but below one is working and routing to error page
>
> RewriteRule  /acheck5.1/test/wcheck/logout
>   https://www-test.com/acheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to mentioned like below.

RewriteRule /acheck*/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/logout https://www-test.com/acheck